# How to update like "UPDATE table SET col1='val1'" in GreenDao

Tags: java, android, greendao

I just can't find how to only update a few columns.

```
Table table = new Table(1);
table.setName("name111");

tableDao.update(table);
```

My understanding would be: "`UPDATE table SET name = 'name111' where id = 1`";

How can do it?

Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html  try here

Comment: Sure I can do it raw SQL, but what is the point to use greendao?

Comment: Read this http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/faq/

Comment: Can you point me to the relevant section?

Comment: Does your entity already exist in the database? To be sure: Try to do a select first, then modify then update.

Comment: What would be the syntax for greendao? Raw sql is simple.

Answer (score 2):

Just return the rows you want to update as a list and loop over them

```
final List<Wine> wines = SQLiteOpen.wineDao.queryBuilder().where(WineDao.Properties.VintageId.eq(vintageId)).list();
for(Wine wine : wines) {
    wine.setWishlist(true);
    wine.update();
}
```

Comment: No chances to do the same in one step for multiple rows without slow iteration in java-bytecode side?

Comment: I'd simply do this in SQL and use the GreenDao properties to ensure column names and property names can be modified dynamically without braking the hardcoded SQL. I've done this with great success in a huge project.

Answer (score -3):

Just Go Through Documentation [here](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/)

Comment: I only see how to make a "SELECT"?

Comment: http://androidvenkatkrishna.blogspot.in/2013/01/green-dao-implementation-in-android.html